# OneNote keeps asking for a password

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-onenote, windows-10-preview, microsoft-onenote-2013

OneNote just keeps asking for a password and refuses to sync my Notebooks. I've reinstalled Office but it is still asking for that password. Clicking the message doesn't do anything. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with the saved credentials.

1. Open **Credential Manager** in Control Panel.
2. Delete the credentials containing "live", e.g. "MicrosoftOffie15_Data:live:cid=12345678".
3. Re-open OneNote and sign in again.

Source: [Seirer.net](http://www.seirer.net/blog/2012/12/5/onenote-2013-suddenly-not-synching-with-skydrive-anymore)